# React Redux composition

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-redux

I want to recreate typical UI pattern using `React and Redux` - `Modal Window` with `data form` containing `4 inputs/selects UI elements`.
I read a lot about smart-container components and dumb presentational components, but don't have enough practice to figure out the best composition pattern in this particular case.

Currently I figured out the following components to compose:

```
<ModalContainer />
<ModalWindow />
<Form />
<Input 1/> ... <Input 2/>
```

Please, advice:

1. Witch components should be considered Smart and Dumb?
2. How to implement proper data flow with Redux?
3. How component composition may look like in this case?
4. Any canonical code samples or blogs to read about?

Answer (score 0):

**Which components should be considered Smart and Dumb?**

All your logic should be there in the your smart components aka containers, you get all data in here and pass that on to your presentational components which only render components(nothing else, that is why they are called dumb). There is an amazing article regarding this [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.2s0269f24) which explains it really well.

**How to implement proper data flow with Redux?**

Well I would say this question is really broad and redux [docs](http://redux.js.org/) itself are a really good way to understand this.

**How component composition may look like in this case?**

**ModalContainer.js**

```
class ModalContainer extends React.Component{
   render(){
   return <Modal {...this.props} />
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
 //map your dispatches here
}

export default connect()(ModalContainer)
```

**Modal.js**

```
class Modal extends React.Component{
  render() {
    // you can change your modal content here based on some props, make it more generic
     <Form {...this.props}/>
  }
}

export default Modal
```

**Form.js**

```
class Form extends React.Component{

  onSubmit () {
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    //dispatch your action here to call API and update store
  }
  render() {
     <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)>
        //form data
     </Form>
  }
}

export default Form
```

P.S:

1. You can make it more generic by creating a FormWrapper which based on props gives you back a particular Form in your modal(in other words you can change the content of modal and use same modal everywhere)
2. The above code is just a demo code to show you how you can compose your components but should work with little modification.

**Any canonical code samples or blogs to read about?**

[Sound Redux](https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux) - I found this code really clean and helpful in the beginning.

Please ask if you need anything else

Comment: Thanks! Now it looks much clearer to me.
But still some questions left. 
According to our project requirements and this beautiful article https://hackernoon.com/redux-step-by-step-a-simple-and-robust-workflow-for-real-life-apps-1fdf7df46092#.kezmtfuszv - 
Dumb components should not access store and dispatch any actions...
So should I consider the Form as a smart component inside dumb <Modal> or it will be better to lift the events up, to be implemented by smart ModalContainer?